# Getting console output from jar in c#

Tags: c#, java, command-line, jar

i have a jar which if i run from the command line returns me a true or false printed to the console

i am trying to run this from c# and obtain the result - this is being done like this

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", @"-jar test.jar " + paramterForStringArgs[0]);
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
String s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
Trace.WriteLine("data = " + s);
return false;
```

I seem to be always getting an empty string and was wondering why this might be, or if there was a better way of doing it?

Comment: Try to do it with the command "java.exe -version" and see if that works first.

Comment: You may also need to set RedirectStandardError and call p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().

Comment: redirecting to the stderror stream allowed me to see the error that the jar wasn't accessible. I forgot to set copy to output directory to copy if newer - i wasted every ones time. sorry - but it works - yay :)

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers, You might want to create an answer so he can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `RedirectStandardError` and calling `p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` reads any error output from the process.